# FieldChangeListener for an element in GridFieldManager

Tags: blackberry

I am developing an app for BB 9700 with OS 5. Right now in my program I have a GridFieldManager loaded with bunch of elements in type of horizontalFieldManagers. I noticed that after adding those managers to GridFieldManager and calling getFieldAtIndex to my GridFieldManager, it will return me a FIELD. Can I set a FieldChangeListener to this returned field? What I know is I could not do it to HorizontalFieldManager. But can I do it to this returned field?

My intention is to create a list, that whenever you click one of the element, it will change the content of the gridfieldmanager.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to set a FieldChangeListener on the field returned from getFieldAtIndex()? And the field returned happens to be a HorizontalFieldManager - is that correct?

If so, then you should be able to set a new change listener like so:
`gridField.getFieldAtIndex(0).setChangeListener(newChangeListener);`

I'm not sure if that's what you're asking - so feel free to elaborate a bit more if this isn't the answer you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Manager is a subclass of Field - that's why it's returned as a field by the GridFieldManager, from what I can decipher in your post you're attempting to get around the fact that you can't assign a change listener to a Manager... why would you ever want to do that anyway? Maybe go back to the basics of fields and managers and you'll see an easy way of doing what you're trying.